# Smoke constrained by objects

Tags: smoke-simulation, collision

I have a smoke emitter that is under a rocket (but not touching anything). It emits smoke, but the smoke just sits there in a bubble. It doesn't flow. If I move the emitter away from the collision objects, it works fine. It's like the smoke won't get within a meter of any collision object, and this is a threshold that I can't seem to edit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem could be the Resolution of the smoke domain as smoke will not enter a 'cell' that overlaps the obstacle. This is illustrated by the following image :

[image: smoke grid obstacle]

This is using a Smoke Domain Resolution of 64 - meaning that the 'cell' size is 1/64th of the longest X,Y,Z dimension of the smoke domain.

As you can see, the influence of the obstacle is 'stepped', clearly showing the individual grid cells. For 'flat' non-rotated surfaces this can be seen as a considerable gap between smoke and obstacle.

Choosing a much larger Resolution will reduce the size of the cells and the resulting in smoke that can get much closer to the obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the boundaries of the Smoke Domain?

The Smoke Domain is a cube that determines the limits of the simulation of the smoke. It cannot escape it. The cube can be resized and it's shape changed, of course.

Here's the [relevant page from the Blender Manual for 2.79.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/domain.html)